# How to set date format like (24-Jun-15) with a calendar?

Tags: php, html, date, datepicker

I created a web form using PHP. In this form there is a field with input type "date" where I want to change the format of said date. But when I change the attribute it's not working.

```
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"/>
```

When I change it into

```
<input type="date" value="<?php echo date('d-M-y');?>"/>
```

It's not working. I want to display my date as
[image: date]

How I can do it?

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php echo'MB | Falcons | '  ?> 
<?php echo date("d M"); ?>
    <table width="664" >
    <tr>
        <td height="34"  colspan="6" class="DivSubHeaderCellTop"><p>  Morning Breifing</p></td>
</tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td  colspan="6" class="DivSubHeaderCellTop">Upload File</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td> <td>   MB | Falcons</td> <td width="154"><input type="date" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>"/> </td>
 </tr>
    <tr> <td width="157" height="23">&nbsp;</td> </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="4" bordercolorlight="#006666">  <input type="file" name="files[]"  multiple/> </td>
    <td width="215">
      <input type="submit"/>
   </td>
    <tr>
    <td height="75">
    </td>
    <td width="116">
    
   </td> </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: have you read documentation of this date-picker js? you will get answer in this documentation...you need to set format using jquery/javascript

Comment: As I believe it's a more datepicker jquery question, please read: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat `$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});`

Comment: @Prafulla you mean i use Jquery or Javascript?

Comment: @Uchiha am using HTNL5

Comment: @OfirBaruch Can i use it in Input Type="date" or not?

Comment: refer this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php date function is fine. The problem is that you need to define that format also with your `datepicker` settings.

**Update:** Just noticed that you're using the HTML5 feature which according to the manual doesn't allow date format modifications. Consider using the jquery ui plugin and follow the instructions below. (Consider also reading about [`jquery ui`](http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/) if you're not already familiar with it)

According to the [jquery ui datepicker docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat), you should set the format like that:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
});
```

You can see the possible date formats here: [Date Format](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)

In case you want '24-Jun-15', you can use the following:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-M-y"
});
```

You might wish to replace `dd` with `d` for no leading zeroes.

Comment: Ofir Baruch Thank you so much. Just please tell me how i can use it? can i use it into Input type or seprate?

Comment: please i need some more help of you. please see above my code and tell me where i put this jquery code?

Comment: This is the tutorial that would help you: http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('dd ([ \t.-])* m ([ \t.-])* y h:i:s A');
```

output like "30-June 2008"

Or refer  [date format manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: The OP's php code is fine. I believe the problem is the conflict with the jquery ui datepicker plugin.

Comment: Op is aware of `date` function

Answer (score 0):

You can change date format using php as example below

```
$original = "2010-03-21";
$new = date("d-M-Y", strtotime($original));
```

and put variable `$new` to your input tag as

```
 <input type="date" value="<?php echo date('d-M-y');?>"/>
```

hope your problem will going to resolve by this.